# javascript set location sending JSON data

Tags: javascript, html, json

What I'm trying to do is the functional equivalent of setting the "location" property in javascript, but I want to send along JSON encoded data to the server. I don't want to use AJAX, I want to completely replace my page contents with whatever the server sends back.

I think I might be able to do what I want by using `form.submit` by setting the form `enctype` attribute to `application/json`, but I don't know how to get my JSON into the form data set. Is it possible to do this?

Comment: No it is not possible using javascript without ajax

Comment: using what server side language?

Comment: Do you have control over the server script?

Answer (score 2):

You could send the JSON as the query component of the URL:

```
document.location.href = server_url + "?" + encodeURIComponent(json_string);
```

Answer (score 1):

One way of doing it is with a form like this (not as clean as you would like it to be, but if you do not want to use AJAX your choices are quite limited):

```
<form action="json.php" method="post">
    <input type="hidden" name="json" value="{'x':1}" />
</form>
```

Comment: If I do something like this, though, what I will end up sending to the server would be something like "json=[urlencoded myjson]". That's useable, but it isn't really what I want, what I want to do is just send the json itself, not as the value of a name-value pair and without urlencoding. It may not be possible to do this, but it seems strange to me that I can do it with AJAX but not without.

Comment: @gmweinberg This is what HTML can offer. With Javascript and XMLHttpRequest you have a much wider range of options.

Answer (score 0):

you could set an input value to stringified JSON when submitting the form:

```
<form method="post" action="myscript.php" onsubmit="DoSubmit();">
    <input type="hidden" id="myjsoninput" name="json" value="{'x':1}" />
    <input type="submit" name="submit" />
</form>

function DoSubmit(){
  document.getElementById("myjsoninput").value = JSON.stringify({a:'b'});
  return true;
}
```